# Flask SQLAlchemy - Edit and update rows from webpage

Tags: python-2.7, flask-sqlalchemy

I created a db table with multiple rows and columns using flask-sqlalchemy. My requirement is I need to update the data of few columns in the rows  from webpage regularly. Is it possible to edit and update the rows in the tables from webpage using flask sqlalchemy? Can some one share an example so I can get a better understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you have a model defined like this:

```
class Row(db.Model)
    __tablename__ = 'YourTableName'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255))
```

You'd need to build an appropriate HTML form to meet the needs of your specific use case (this could be accomplished without a form, but this is the simplest example):

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('update_row') }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter new name">
</form>
```

Then you have a view function, which is receiving this form input via a `POST` request, to update a specific row:

```
@app.route('/update_row/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def update_row():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # query.get() method gets a Row by the primary_key
        record = Row.query.get(request.form.get('id', type=int))
        # change the values you want to update
        record.name = request.form.get('name')
        # commit changes
        db.session.commit()
    # redirect back to your main view
    return redirect(url_for('main'))
```

You'd obviously want to add validation for things like making sure the name is not blank, or whatever other data checks are appropriate to your use case.

Comment: I have multiple rows in the table so instead of taking value="1", can you let me know how to get the value from the html request form.